# How to save filename to database?

Tags: yii, yii2

I want to add filename to database (to `$model->photo_url`) when I upload a photo and I get an error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'photo_url' doesn't have a default value
```

I tried to assign `$filename` to `$photo_url` after `saveAs()` but it doesn't work.

Controller:

```
public function actionCreate() {
    $model = new Doctors();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $model->image = \yii\web\UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image');

        if ($model->save()) {
              $model->uploadPhoto();
            $model->photo_url = $model->fileName;               
            $this->saveSpecialities($model);               
        }
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    }
    return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model
    ]);
}

//
protected function saveSpecialities($model) {
    foreach ($model->specialites as $var) {
        $speciality = new DoctorsSpeciality();
        $speciality->speciality_id = $var->id;
        $speciality->doctor_id = $model->id;
        $speciality->save();
    }
}
```

Model

```
public function uploadPhoto() {
    if ($this->validate()) {
        $this->fileName = $this->generateSlug() . '.' . $this->image->extension;            
        $this->image->saveAs($this->path . $this->fileName);
        Image::thumbnail($this->path . $this->fileName, 200, 200)->save($this->path_middle . $this->fileName, ['quality' => 100]);
        Image::thumbnail($this->path . $this->fileName, 100, 100)->save($this->path_small . $this->fileName, ['quality' => 100]);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

protected function generateSlug() {
    return Inflector::slug($this->lastname . '-' . $this->middlename . '-' . $this->firstname . '-' . $this->title);
}
```

All files are saved correctly to folders, but how can I save `$this->fileName` to `$this->photoUrl`?

P.S. When I try to do `$this->photo_url = $this->fileName;` in model I get the same error about default value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set field before trying to save model:

```
if ($model->uploadPhoto() && $model->save()) {             
    $this->saveSpecialities($model);               
}
```

And then set `photo_url` inside of `uploadPhoto()`:

```
public function uploadPhoto() {
    if ($this->validate()) {
        $this->fileName = $this->generateSlug() . '.' . $this->image->extension;  
        $this->photo_url = $this->fileName;            
        $this->image->saveAs($this->path . $this->fileName);
        Image::thumbnail($this->path . $this->fileName, 200, 200)->save($this->path_middle . $this->fileName, ['quality' => 100]);
        Image::thumbnail($this->path . $this->fileName, 100, 100)->save($this->path_small . $this->fileName, ['quality' => 100]);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

for this (SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'photo_url' doesn't have a default value)

Solution:
Set a default value for Created_By (eg: empty VARCHAR) and the trigger will be update the value anyways.